Delete attachments from item moved from inbox by rule
Currently attempting to save attachments from mails coming in from a specific email address and then remove all attachments from the mail.
The save works but the attachments are not removed from the stored mail.
Sub SaveAttachmentsFromSelectedItemsPDF(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

    Set attachs = Item.Attachments
    Dim currentAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = attachs.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set currentAttachment = attachs.Item(i)
        If UCase(Right(currentAttachment.DisplayName, 4)) = ".PDF" Then
            file = currentAttachment.FileName
            currentAttachment.SaveAsFile "C:\test\" & file
            Item.Attachments.Remove i
        End If
    Next
    Item.Save

End Sub

I tried multiple formats (including putting the i in parentheses) as well as deleting "CurrentAttachment" every loop.
The rule:

when mail received from (test address)
move it to ATTACHMENT folder then execute SaveAttachmentScript and mark it as read


@KJ
Thanks for the fast reply. I don't understand your suggestion however. I am using the .Remove command listed on that source in the same context as it is used in the given example (using attachs.Remove doesn't work either).
As for the earlier method you provided a link to, I based my own code off of it : you will notice my attachments deleting method is identical to it, using a for loop to count down in reverse order and using the .Remove command to remove the attachment associated with the index of the current loop value, before saving the item at the end of the script.

On the topic of attachs.Item(i), as mentioned in the original post the "saving .PDF files to the hard drive" functionality works as intended so it is properly pointing to the desired attachment on every loop.
I have replaced "Item.Attachments.Remove i" with "attachs.Remove i" as recommended.

@KJ
Thanks again for the continuous support. I have applied all your recommendations and have also put in place a feedback var in order to debug the failing step.
The Count variable is properly counting down from the nuber of attachments in the mail to 1, so the issue isn't there.
The attachments are still properly saving into the correct folder, the only line of code that seems to not be working is the line requesting the removal of the attachments.

Are you testing with a received item to determine whether it is a code problem rather than a rule problem.

@niton
Thanks for the reply. Yes, I have been testing my script by sending mails containing several PDF attachments to my main inbox.
The rule I have set in place goes as follows :

when received mail from (test address)
move it to ATTACHMENT folder
then execute SaveAttachmentScript
and mark it as read.

The mails are properly being sent to the correct folder in outlook and the PDF attachments are correctly being saved, but are not removed from the copy of the mail stored in the inbox.

Other posts indicate moving mail makes RunAScript more unreliable than usual. Try ItemAdd

Move Item in the code rather than the rule, after the save.
Sub SaveAttachmentsFromSelectedItemsPDF(Item As MailItem)

    Dim attachs As Attachments
    Set attachs = Item.Attachments
    
    Dim currentAttachment As Attachment
    Dim file As String
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = attachs.count To 1 Step -1
        Set currentAttachment = attachs.Item(i)
        
         ' Inconsistency may have an impact
        Debug.Print "currentAttachment.DisplayName: " & currentAttachment.DisplayName
        Debug.Print "   currentAttachment.fileName: " & currentAttachment.fileName
        
        If UCase(Right(currentAttachment.DisplayName, 4)) = ".PDF" Then
            file = currentAttachment.fileName
            currentAttachment.SaveAsFile "C:\test\" & file
            Item.Attachments.Remove i
        End If
    Next
    Item.Save
    
    Dim myInbox As folder
    Dim attFolder As folder
    
    ' Default Inbox
    Set myInbox = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    ' One level under default Inbox
    ' Add .Folders as necessary
    Set attFolder = myInbox.Folders("ATTACHMENT")
    
    Item.Move attFolder

End Sub

